# tableViewについてwithIdentifierで指定したIdentifierが有効とならない

Tags: swift, swift3

■実現したいこと
自作セルとStoryboard上に別で配置したCellを組み合わせて、textFiledのCellとチェックマークのCellを表示させたいと考えております。

■問題点
Identifierで指定した値（今回の場合、「SexCell」という値）が有効とならず、上手く対象のセルを期待どおりに表示させることができません。
今回の場合、性別のCellに対し、チェックマークを指定おりますが、下記の表示結果のとおり、自作セルの状態となり、テキストフィールド状態となってしまいます。

■Storyboard上の設定
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

■表示結果
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

■現状のソースコード
・RegisterViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class RegisterViewController:     UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,RegisterDelegate{

    @IBAction func unwindToRegister(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var registerTableView: UITableView!


    //データ
    var dataList = [["ユーザー名"],["パスワード","パスワード(    確認用)"],["メールアドレス","メールアドレス(確認用)"],["男性","女性"]]

    //セクション
    var sectionIndex:[String] =     ["ユーザー名","パスワード","メールアドレス","性別"]

    //データを返すメソッド
    func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAt     indexPath:IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            //セルを取得して値を設定する。
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:     "RegisterCell", for:indexPath as IndexPath) as!     RegisterTableViewCell
            var register = dataList[indexPath.section]
            cell.registerTextField.placeholder = register[indexPath.row]
            //自作セルのデリゲート先に自分を設定する。
            cell.delegate = self
            return cell
        }else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            //セルを取得して値を設定する。
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:     "RegisterCell", for:indexPath as IndexPath) as!     RegisterTableViewCell
            var register = dataList[indexPath.section]
            cell.registerTextField.placeholder = register[indexPath.row]
            cell.registerTextField.isSecureTextEntry = true
            //自作セルのデリゲート先に自分を設定する。
            cell.delegate = self
            return cell
        }else if indexPath.section == 2 {
            //セルを取得して値を設定する。
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:     "RegisterCell", for:indexPath as IndexPath) as!     RegisterTableViewCell
            var register = dataList[indexPath.section]
            cell.registerTextField.placeholder = register[indexPath.row]
            //自作セルのデリゲート先に自分を設定する。
            cell.delegate = self
            return cell
        }else if indexPath.section == 3{
            //セルを取得して値を設定する。
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:     "RegisterCell", for:indexPath as IndexPath) as!     RegisterTableViewCell
            var register = dataList[indexPath.section]
            cell.registerTextField.placeholder = register[indexPath.row]
            //自作セルのデリゲート先に自分を設定する。
            cell.delegate = self
            return cell
        }else {
            //セルを取得する。
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:     "SexCell", for:indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            var test = dataList[indexPath.section]
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            cell.textLabel?.text = test[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
    }

    //データの個数を返すメソッド
    func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection     section:Int) -> Int {
        return dataList[section].count
    }

    //セクション名を返す
    func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection     section:Int) -> String?{
        return sectionIndex[section]
    }

    //セクションの個数を返す
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sectionIndex.count
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from     a nib.
        //自作セルをテーブルビューに登録する。
        let testXib = UINib(nibName:"RegisterTableViewCell", bundle:nil)
        registerTableView.register(testXib,     forCellReuseIdentifier:"RegisterCell")

    }

    //デリゲートメソッド
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(cell: RegisterTableViewCell,     value:String) {
        //変更されたセルのインデックスを取得する。
        let index = registerTableView.indexPathForRow(at: cell.convert(    cell.bounds.origin, to:registerTableView))

        //データを変更する。
        let sec = index!.section
        let row = index!.row

        dataList[sec][row] = value
        print(value)
        print(dataList)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

・RegisterTableViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit


//デリゲート先に適用してもらうプロトコル
protocol RegisterDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(cell:RegisterTableViewCell, value:String)
}

class RegisterTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var registerTextField: UITextField!

    var delegate:RegisterDelegate! = nil

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        //テキストフィールドのデリゲート先を自分に設定する。
        registerTextField.delegate = self
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }


    //デリゲートメソッド
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        //キーボードを閉じる。
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }


    //デリゲートメソッド
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        //テキストフィールドから受けた通知をデリゲート先に流す。
        self.delegate.textFieldDidEndEditing(cell: self, value:     registerTextField.text!)
    }


}
```

Comment: セクションの数はユーザー名、パスワード、メールアドレス、性別の4つですが、`tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:IndexPath)`メソッド内の、セクションごとの条件分岐が5つありますね。

Comment: @nagonsoftware様、早速のコメントありがとうございます。セクションの条件分岐が多かったことが原因でした。凡ミスでした。。。申し訳ございません。。。後ほど回答に記載させていただきます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

上記のコメントでも頂いているとおり、セクションの条件分岐が多かったことが原因でした。セクション数に合わせて条件分岐を修正したところ正しく動作いたしました。今後、tableViewを利用する際は、セクション数と条件分岐の数が適切か確認したいと思います。